# can anyone help on this Unhandled exception in internal background task 'updater'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

THE COMPLETE ERROR
[image]

import discord
import requests
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from parse import parse

```js
# Token of the bot
TOKEN = 'MTAzMTg1OTQ0NjkwMjY4NTczNw.G04dKa.oVTy6yTNhTz-1iVTcZGrNsgL0jlllHDxMF8eoc' # enter your bot token here
# instagram account names
INSTAGRAM_ACCOUNTS = ['']
# channel id where the images are posted
CHANNEL_ID = 1002978952362590258 # replace by your channel id
# limit of the message history read when checking if latest instagram publications have already been posted in the channel
MESSAGE_HISTORY_LIMIT = 100
# color of the messages
COLOR = 0x05c0ec
# time in seconds after which an update check is performed
UPDATE_INTERVAL = 200
# requests timeout
TIMEOUT = 5
# header for sending requests to Instagram
HEADER = {
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding": "de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Cookie": "55835706314%3AQ295uVglvDnGMQ%3A9%3AAYc7TcEL-KjTOnrwvMPw-BCFt6t-TDD0rW97wk-mdg", # enter your cookie here
        "Host": "www.instagram.com",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
        "TE": "trailers",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0"
}

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="~~", intents=discord.Intents.all())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')
    updater.start()


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)


@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    print("Ping received")
    await ctx.channel.send('pong')


@bot.command()
async def update(ctx):
    print("Force updating")
    await update_from_instagram(bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID))


@tasks.loop(seconds=UPDATE_INTERVAL)
async def updater():
    await update_from_instagram(bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID))


async def update_from_instagram(channel):
    last_published_images_codes = []
    async for message in channel.history(limit=MESSAGE_HISTORY_LIMIT):
        for embed in message.embeds:
            code = parse('https://www.instagram.com/p/{}/', embed.url)
            if code is not None:
                last_published_images_codes.append(str(code[0]))
    images_data = {}
    users_data = {}
    for username in INSTAGRAM_ACCOUNTS:
        user_data = get_user_data(username)
        if user_data is not None:
            users_data[username] = user_data
            images_data[username] = get_last_image_data(user_data)
        else:
            print(username + ": Failed to update")

    for username in images_data:
        if images_data[username]["shortcode"] not in last_published_images_codes:
            await post_image(channel, username, users_data[username], images_data[username])
            print(username + ": New image to post in discord")
        else:
            print(username + ": No new image to post in discord")


# post embedded image to discord channel
async def post_image(channel, username, user_data, image_data):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Neuer Beitrag von @" + str(username),
                          url="https://www.instagram.com/p/{}/".format(image_data["shortcode"]),
                          description=image_data["edge_media_to_caption"]["edges"][0]["node"]["text"],
                          color=COLOR)
    embed.set_author(name=user_data["full_name"],
                     url="https://www.instagram.com/{}/".format(username),
                     icon_url=user_data["profile_pic_url"])
    embed.set_image(url=image_data["display_url"])
    embed.set_footer(text="Gefällt {} Mal\n{} Kommentare".format(image_data["edge_liked_by"]["count"], image_data["edge_media_to_comment"]["count"]))
    await channel.send(embed=embed)


# returns json data of the specified account
def get_user_data(username):
    response = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/" + str(username) + "/?__a=1&__d=dis", headers=HEADER, timeout=TIMEOUT)
    try:
        return response.json()["graphql"]["user"]
    except:
        return None


# returns json data of the latest image available on the specified instagram account
def get_last_image_data(user_data):
    return user_data["edge_owner_to_timeline_media"]["edges"][0]["node"]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.run(TOKEN)
```

everything works fine until i get this error at the end "Unhandled exception in internal background task 'updater'". Any help would be great , using py 3.8 , all requirements are satisfied , seems like an rare error

Comment: Hi, try to minimize your code to the essential parts. Also please provide a full / good enough traceback with the line where it happens.

Comment: And don't reaveal your bot tokens. Regenerate it as soon as possible+

Comment: hello @Daraan just added the whole error , and yes regenerated

Answer (score 1):

Generalized you can think about discord.py adding another layer to python.

When an error happens and an exception is thrown,
to keep your code running, **discord tries to handle the errors**, or rather gives you the chance to handle the errors mostly in the `on_error` event.
When they are not handled they are forwarded and **often stacked/wrapped with another exception.**
This sometimes **makes it harder to see the real error**

---

The unhandled exception in `updater` is actually a **TypeError** from `parse` in your function `def updater`.
Because it was not handled it reached the next level of discord which den threw this more ambigous error.
In discord when you get an error always look up the traceback if there is another - the real - error behind it.
Always try to check your tracebacks in which line does it happen? Is a underlying exception the case and a reraise happend.

---

So this is your line that causes the error:

```
code = parse('https://www.instagram.com/p/{}/', embed.url)
```

And one of these two has the wrong type. The first is obviously a string. So `embed.url` is not a string.
With a look in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.url) the type for `embed.url` is `Optional[str]` this means **embed.url can be None** or in an unlikely case is not set, but then you would get an AttributeError.

---

So **you need to check if embed.url is actually a string before calling parse**

```py
for embed in message.embeds:
    if isinstance(embed.url, str):
        code = parse('https://www.instagram.com/p/{}/', embed.url)
        if code is not None:
            last_published_images_codes.append(str(code[0]))
```